# HP logo disappears while booting Windows 10. Loading never finishes. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-10-v1607

I recently updated to the Anniversary Update of Windows 10. Unfortunately, like all big Windows updates, it has a lot of bugs. I've done a lot of research on this issue that I get, but I can't find anyone with the same problem, let alone an answer to this issue. When I turn on my computer, it loads normally, but after a few seconds, the HP logo about the spinning circle disappears. The spinning circle remains and the boot never finishes. I can enter safe mode and I am 100% positive this is not caused by a virus of some sort. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Shut down my computer and restarted. Happened again. I though I was doomed. Out of desperation I held <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and somehow it loaded! SO HAPPY MY COMPUTER IS FUNCTIONING AGAIN!!!

UPDATE: As it turns out, a combination of unplugging USB devices, turning the computer on/off, removing the battery and holding the power button, and Ctrl + Alt + Del fixes it most of the time for me.

Comment: hahahaha, that is the most random solution ever. Can't imagine why it worked

Comment: I assume this worked because the black screen with the loading sign was simply covering the actual screen with the login. And yeah, I was surprised this worked too.